# Find the data prior to query mark "?" in URL

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have a incoming url 
`"website.com/cc/1234?abc=5678"` i need to redirect it to `"website.com/d/e/g?def=1234&abc=5678"`.

I used Rewrite rule :

```
RewriteRule ^/cc/(.+)?(.+)  https://website.com/d/e/g?def=$1&$2.
```

For the above rewrite rule i got output as :

```
https://website.com/d/e/g?def=123&4&abc=5678
```

Can someone help in writing the rewrite rule which will redirect to `https://website.com/d/e/g?def=1234&abc=5678`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **QSA** flag to acheive this, like below.

```
RewriteRule ^/cc/(.+)  https://website.com/d/e/g?def=$1 [QSA]
```

Please refer http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html for more details.